# How to develope server side application for Blackberry Push Notification(Facing Error)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, blackberry, blackberry-push

I am using below code to make notifier on server for Blackberry Push Notification, but getting error showing below.
  Can anyone help me please to develope server side application for blackberry push notification in java.

```
    Exception in thread "main" net.rim.pushsdk.commons.PushSDKException: Bad HTTP response      returned: HttpResponse ( net.rim.pushsdk.commons.http.HttpResponse@10a93e5    statusCode = 404    content = https://cp****.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com    contentType = null    headerFields = {null=[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found], Date=[Tue, 11 Jun 2013 12:38:52 GMT], Content-Length=[0], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1]}     )
 at net.rim.pushsdk.pap.PapServiceImpl.sendToPpg(PapServiceImpl.java:480)
 at net.rim.pushsdk.pap.PapServiceImpl.pushToPpg(PapServiceImpl.java:446)
 at net.rim.pushsdk.pap.PapServiceImpl.push(PapServiceImpl.java:174)
 at BBM.main(BBM.java:82)
```

/******************************/

/*************************************************************************/

```
 import java.sql.Date;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.sym;

    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.IdGenerator;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.IdGeneratorImpl;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.PushSDKException;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.PushSDKProperties;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.PushSDKPropertiesImpl;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.UnauthorizedException;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.content.Content;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.content.TextContent;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.commons.http.HttpClientImpl;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.pap.PapBeanLocator;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.pap.PapService;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.pap.PapServiceImpl;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.pap.StatusCode;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.pap.control.PushMessageControl;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.pap.unmarshal.BadMessageException;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.pap.unmarshal.PushResponse;
    import net.rim.pushsdk.pap.unmarshal.ResponseResult;

    public class BBM {
     private static String password = "********";

     private static String targetURL = "https://cp****.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";

     private static final String APP_ID = "****-***********************************";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws PushSDKException,
       BadMessageException, UnauthorizedException {
      org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 b6;
      // net.rim.pushsdk.acknowledgement.NotificationProcessorServiceImpl nsi;
      IdGenerator idGenerator = new IdGeneratorImpl();
      List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
      String data = "this is a test message – 2";
      System.out.println("Data is: " + data);
      addresses.add("********");
      PushMessageControl pushMessageControl = new PushMessageControl(true,
        idGenerator, APP_ID, addresses);
      Content content = new TextContent(data);
      PapService papService = new PapServiceImpl();
      PushSDKProperties properties = getBBProperties();
      HttpClientImpl client = new HttpClientImpl();
      client.setPushSDKProperties(properties);
      papService.setHttpClient(client);
      papService.setPushSDKProperties(properties);
      PushResponse response = papService.push(APP_ID, password, APP_ID,
        pushMessageControl, content);
       ResponseResult result = response.getResult();
        StatusCode statusCode = result.getCode();
        String code = statusCode.getCode();
        String description = result.getDescription();
        System.out.println(""+statusCode+":"+description+":"+code);
      System.out.println(response.getDescription());
     private static PushSDKProperties getBBProperties() {
      PushSDKProperties p = new PushSDKPropertiesImpl();
      p.setPublicPpgAddress(targetURL);
      p.setHttpIsPersistent(true);
      p.setHttpConnectionTimeout(60000);
      p.setHttpReadTimeout(120000);
        return p;
     }
    }
```

Comment: check this http://goo.gl/nl7qo